# Очень долгий поиск по первичному ключу - WHERE id IN (x1, x2, x3)

Tags: mariadb

Сервер 4core/64GB RAM/30GB SSD

Ubuntu 22, MariaDB: 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1

Нагрузка на сервер нулевая.

Таблица с 3млн записей:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    `id` INT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE, 
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Делаю запрос по первичному ключу используя IN:

```
SELECT id FROM `t1` WHERE id IN (123,2352,2423);
```

Запрос выполняется очень долго - 3 секунды.

В таком варианте время выполнения аналогично:

```
SELECT id FROM `t1` WHERE id=123 OR id=2352 OR id=2423;
```

Если же пробовать выполнить запрос

```
SELECT id FROM `t1` WHERE id>2352 AND id<2362
```

то результат получаю мгновенно.

Почему с параметром "IN" запрос по первичному ключу такой долгий? В mySQL с аналогичными параметрами сервера и настроек таких проблем не возникало.

Comment: Таблица секционирована? Статистика обновлена? Можешь план запроса приложить?

Comment: спасибо, решил проблему. Ответ ниже

Comment: про секционирование и обновление статистики можно подробнее ? это как и где делается?

Comment: @Ruoort лучше потом почитать про это, в комментарий не уложусь) для оптимизации работы применяются

Answer (score 0):

Проблему устранил оптимизацией таблицы ))) : OPTIMIZE TABLE t1;

До этого переносил БД с СУБД mySQL с помощью mysqldump, и выполнением полученного .sql (куча запросов INSERT) на новой машине с СУБД mariaDB.

Возможно при импорте конечный оператор включения индексов не был выполнен и импорт был не полностью завершен. (недоглядел)